# Xcode: How to keep IB & Assistant editor opened when app crashes in simulator or debug is enabled

Tags: xcode, storyboard, interface-builder

During editing I keep open Interface Builder on left and Assistant editor on right side. When a breakpoint is added or when the app crashes during runtime, the Interface Builder pane disappears, and it shows file which has breakpoint or crash. It's annoying as I've to go back to IB after each such instance and it takes too much of my time.

Is there anyway I can stop Interface Builder disappearing and crash/breakpoint file to be shown on Assistant editor or in any other window?

Comment: That is a Behavior preference.

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround would be simply to duplicate the current window by using keyboard shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> before hitting run.

That way when the breakpoint hits the offending line, it will happen in the new window which you can simply close, and resume work in your old, organised editor environment.

Comment: It may be the solution but again it involves click which is what I wanted to avoid at first place. Seems we don't have any solution.